# problema al buscar guias para ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Soy nueva en el desarrollo con nuevas tecnologias
¿Quiero saber cual es el mejor tutorial o videotutorial para aprender react js ?

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Preguntas que no son relacionadas a dudas de programación o basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, lee [ask]

Comment: Preguntas como esta se basa en opiniones, de igual manera existen plataformas en español como udemy o platzi ,